# Non-invariant vector field. Example.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $F:M\to M$ be a diffeomorphism, and $X$ be a vector field on $M$ i.e. $X\in TM$.

We say that $X$ is invariant if
$$X(F(a))=F_*X(a)$$
for all $a\in M$ where $F^*$ is a pushforward math. I wanted to construct an example of a vector field in this case which is not invariant. Also, I wonder about other examples and about geometric meaning of an invariant vector field.

Consider $M=\mathbb{R}^2$, $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ where $F(x,y)=(y,x)$, and $X(x,y)=(x+1,y)$. Then we can see that this vector field is not invariant as
$$X(F(a))=X(a_2,a_1)=(a_2+1,a_1)\text{ does not equal to}$$
$$F^*X(a)=(a_2,a_1+1).$$

Comment: Your $F^*$ should be a $F_*$ (lower star for push forward, upper for pullback). Your example is fine.

Comment: @TedShifrin, thank you!